# Time Formatting in Lua

Tags: datetime, lua, format, coronasdk, dayofweek

I need this string: 
"2017-09-23T20:00:00-05:00"

To look like this:
"Saturday September 23, 2017"

My main issue is having multiple strings of this format and I'm unable to calculate the weekday.

Comment: Easy way just use some existed libs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to calculate the weekday:

```
local function week_day(year, month, day)
   return
      ({"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"})
      [os.date("*t", os.time{year = year, month = month, day = day}).wday]
end

print(week_day(2017, 9, 19))   --> Tuesday
```

**Note:** please make sure all your dates are within 1970-2037